# process get exited with return value 3221226356

Tags: c, return-value

Whenever I run the following code, and give input as long string it gets exited with the return value 3221226356

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char c,*input;
    input=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(input==NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%d size",strlen(input));
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    while((c=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));
        input[i++]=c;
    }
    printf("%s",input);
}
```

Comment: realloc(input, (sizeof(char))); where is the return value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `realloc` function returns a ***new*** pointer. It doesn't change the pointer you pass to it.

That means after the first call to `realloc` you probably start writing to unallocated memory, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also note that your `realloc` call only allocates *one* byte. You need to allocate the previous size *plus* one.

There's also the problem of you calling `strlen` on a pointer to uninitialized memory (of size one by the way), which *also* leads to undefined behavior.

And since you treat the memory you allocate as a string, you should also allocate space for the string terminator, so the very first allocation should be for *two* bytes.

Another couple of notes: `sizeof(char)` is specified to always result in `1`. And in C [don't cast the result of `malloc` (and family)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 5):

The exit code `0xC0000374` is the value returned when heap corruption is detected.

Where you are reallocating, you do not reallocate more values. You free 1 char worth of memory, and then allocate a new 1 char memory segment. This causes `input[i++]` to access a region outside of the area you allocated.

Comment: Also, the return value of `realloc` is ignored, so `input` might become invalid anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of problems with this code:

1. You cast the result of `malloc`, which is unnecessary
2. You always reallocate only 1 byte with `realloc`, but even given that, you do not do anything with `realloc`'s return value (which is a resized pointer), so nothing useful happens here
3. Since you always have a 1-byte allocation to `input`, you attempt to access memory outside this allocation, which is going to return garbage (if you're lucky enough not to get a seg fault)

Read up on documentation for `malloc` and `realloc` to figure out where your code is going wrong.