# How do I fix this error when I try to run vulcan on meteor? It is given in the body

Tags: node.js, meteor, command-prompt, vulcan, vulcanjs

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. The error message

```
C:\Users\Sean O'Gary\Documents\Vulcan-Starter>npm start

> Vulcan@1.13.4 prestart C:\Users\Sean O'Gary\Documents\Vulcan-Starter
> node .vulcan/prestart_vulcan.js

 ___    ___
 \\\\  ////
  \\\\////    Vulcan.js
   \\\///    The full-stack React+GraphQL framework
    ────
>  Happy hacking with Vulcan!
>  The docs are available at: http://docs.vulcanjs.org

> Vulcan@1.13.4 start C:\Users\Sean O'Gary\Documents\Vulcan-Starter
> meteor --settings settings.json

[[[[[ C:\Users\Sean O'Gary\Documents\Vulcan-Starter ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE..                   /
npm ERR! errno 3221226356
npm ERR! Vulcan@1.13.4 start: `meteor --settings settings.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221226356
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Vulcan@1.13.4 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sean O'Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11- 
07T17_48_59_123Z-debug.log
```

I am simply inexperienced. Initially, it was telling me that I cannot have 
two versions of meteor running and that port 3000 was unavailable. I got rid 
of that by killing meteor related processes in task manager. Yet these error 
messages have not gone away. I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Doing a google on `errno 3221226356`,

I found this answer

[process get exited with return value 3221226356](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987792/process-get-exited-with-return-value-3221226356)

one of the responses suggests some kind of heap corruption, which you shouldn't really get in Meteor in a transpiled environment.

Try rebooting your machine if you haven't already, then I think you should try a `meteor reset`, and worst case remove files in ~/.meteor and reinstall meteor.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll see if that helps.